# Geosever : make line string feature from MongoDB collection

Tags: geoserver, mongodb

I installed the gt-mongo plugin to a geoserver and made a new MongoDB store and here is the collection documents example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2543fcccc8fa54bc0822ac"), 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            22.697815, 
            75.740113
        ]
    }
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2543fcccc8fa54bc0823ca"), 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            25.697815, 
            72.740113
        ]
    }
}
```

and the schema_store JSON file:

```
{
    "typeName": "test",
    "userData": {
        "collection": "test"
    },
    "geometryDescriptor": {
        "localName": "location",
        "crs": {
             "properties": {
                 "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326"
              },
             "type": "name"
        }
    },
    "attributeDescriptors": [
        {
            "localName": "location",
            "type": {
                "binding": "com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point"
            },
            "userData": {
                "encoding": "GeoJSON",
                "mapping": "loc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to serve it as LineString, not as points. any helps?